# Extraneous rollback with Flask-Sqlalchemy for every request

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask application that uses Flask-Sqlalchemy to handle the connections to the DB. One thing that I'm noticing in my application traces is that at the end of every request in my application, there is a `postgres.connection.rollback`. In no place in my code am I performing a rollback, but one is performed on *every* request at the end of every request. Basically, I see the following for all requests:

-> `Save record to DB` -> `postgres.connection.commit` -> `postgres.connection.rollback`

I've looked through the [Flask-Sqlalchemy documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/quickstart/#) and the source code, but I can't seem to figure out where the extraneous rollback is occurring.

Comment: have you checked for triggers?

Comment: How have you discovered a rollback was executed after every query?

Comment: @nbk how would I go about that with Flask?

Comment: @atmo I discovered the addition rollback with Datadog APM traces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQLAlchemy will call a connection's `rollback` method when it is returned to a connection pool. This behaviour is documented at [Reset On Return](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/pooling.html#reset-on-return)

> The pool includes “reset on return” behavior which will call the rollback() method of the DBAPI connection when the connection is returned to the pool. This is so that any existing transactional state is removed from the connection, which includes not just uncommitted data but table and row locks as well. For most DBAPIs, the call to rollback() is inexpensive, and if the DBAPI has already completed a transaction, the method should be a no-op.

The default behaviour can be disabled by passing `pool_reset_on_return=None` to `create_engine`:

```py
engine = create_engine(url, pool_reset_on_return=None)
```

This behaviour can be customised by disabling the default behaviour and providing alternative behaviour in the [reset](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/events.html#sqlalchemy.events.PoolEvents.reset) pool event handler.

Comment: See also https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/faq/connections.html#why-does-sqlalchemy-issue-so-many-rollbacks