# Unwanted Rollback in Postgres - missing data after commit

Tags: postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, pgadmin, rollback

I am trying to create a simple sign-up and login web app using Flask and PostgreSQL in Docker. I also added pgAdmin because I wanted to see my database. My web app has a strange problem. I am able to create new user (sign-up) and then also log in into the user I've created but if I check my database using pgAdmin it is empty. In logs I noticed that after every commit there's a rollback. I've been trying to debug it but with no success.

This is how I create new users :

```
new_user = User(email=email, username=username, password=password)
db.session.add(new_user)
db.session.commit()
login_user(new_user, remember=True)
flash('Account created!', category='success')
return redirect(url_for('home.html'))
```

This is how my User table looks :

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
password = db.Column(db.String(150))
username = db.Column(db.String(150))
```

And this is a Rollback log:

```
"GET /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Created Database! <----------- This is the second creation of database
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT "user".id AS user_id, 
"user".email 
AS user_email, "user".password AS user_password, "user".username AS 
user_username 
FROM "user" 
WHERE "user".email = %(email_1)s 
LIMIT %(param_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00048s] {'email_1': 
'test@test.test', 'param_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO "user" (email, password,             
username) VALUES (%(email)s, %(password)s, %(username)s) RETURNING                 
"user".id
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00041s] {'email':     
'test@test.test', 'password': 'test', 'username': 'test'}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT "user".id AS user_id, 
"user".email     
AS user_email, "user".password AS user_password, "user".username AS         
user_username 
FROM "user" 
WHERE "user".id = %(pk_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00045s] {'pk_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
"POST /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 302 -
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT "user".id AS user_id, 
"user".email AS user_email, "user".password AS user_password, 
"user".username AS user_username 
FROM "user" 
WHERE "user".id = %(pk_1)s
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00040s] {'pk_1': 1}
INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
"GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I have also noticed in logs that the database is created twice. This is how I create a database

```
with app.app_context():   
    db.create_all()
    print('Created Database!')
```

The database gets created in the beggining, which is correct. Below are logs

```
CREATE TABLE "user" (
 id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
 email VARCHAR(150), 
 password VARCHAR(150), 
 username VARCHAR(150), 
 PRIMARY KEY (id), 
 UNIQUE (email)
)
Created Database!
```

And then when I access the sign-up page I get log 'Created Database!' again. Only the print statement.

```
"GET /sign-up HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Created Database!
```

Thank you for your answers and I am sorry if there is anything missing in my snippets. I will gladly provide more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extraneous rollback with Flask-Sqlalchemy for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78014346/extraneous-rollback-with-flask-sqlalchemy-for-every-request)

Comment: The question about the "database created" message should be a separate question (only one question per question) but it won't cause any problems. By default SQLAlchemy will check if a table exists before trying to create ti, and do nothing if the table already exists. Presumably the creation code is being called twice somehow.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but no this did not help.  @snakecharmerb

Comment: I included the database being created twice only because it could be the possible thing that causes rollbacks. Didn't mean to ask 2 questions.

Comment: I was thinking of two possible solutions. 
1. switch to SQLite (I don't really want to do this)
2. switch from SQLAlchemy to psycopg2 - do you think this will work?

Comment: Switching databases will make no difference. The behaviour is defined at the SQLAlchemy level. Switching to psycopg2 will probably make things more difficult for you.  I'd consider adding some print calls inside your sugnup method to see what values you are receiving, and which code paths are being executed.  Also are you refreshing pgadmin after the user is created? Can you see the user in psql?

Comment: Consider creating a [mre] as the issues can't be reproduced with the current code.

Comment: And generally, restructure the question (and title) so that the focus is on the apparently missing data.

Comment: I cannot provide minimal reproducible example, the project is separated to more .py files. I can provide github link from which I forked the project, if it is allowed. To your suggestion : I put the print statements to the first snippet of my post and the everything passes. I also added try/except for sign-up and the 'try' passes. But at the end there's still a rollback

Comment: Your log looks fine, the INSERT should be successful. However, this is not done in a transaction because there is no BEGIN. Your code does sent a COMMIT, but without a BEGIN that's useless. The first and only BEGIN is for the SELECT statement, that makes no sense but doesn't hurt either. The ROLLBACK is for this transaction, but there is nothing to rollback since you didn't insert, update or deleted anything. So there is something else going on. Are you sure you're looking at the same database?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I edited the post and posted full rollback log. Maybe this will help. I want to mention again, that after registering an user I can successfully log in to created user, so the data had to store somewhere I don't know where. And to your question, yes I connect to the right database. I can see the table, with all collumns (id, email, username, password).
I forked from this project on github, but instead of using SQLite I used PostreSQL.
[link](https://github.com/techwithtim/Flask-Web-App-Tutorial) **GitHub**

Comment: The COMMIT is there, so the data must be there. For the rest, this behavior is rather strange to me: Why would you ever want to rollback a SELECT statement? There is nothing to rollback because you didn't change anything. And a rollback suggests that something went really wrong, and that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: locally it works just fine...

Comment: Are you sure the commits are occurring in the same session as user creation? If a new user can log in from where it was created, but can't be seen by other clients accessing the database, then it is likely that the transaction that created the user is still open. In such a situation, no sessions outside of the one that performed the insert will be able to see the effects of the insert.

Comment: @JohnH I tried using simple try/except on commits and also print the session id before and after commit,  which stays the same.

Comment: there must be some kind of problem with session. I can create multiple users and then querry their data and even show them on website but the data do not get passed to the postgres database. In pgadmin after connecting to the database and querrying the data, the database has only one record and that is id:1 user: postgres. I tried connecting dirrectly to the container using shell and container ID with the same result.
Any suggestions?